# How integrated is the bullet engine in blender?

Tags: python, physics

I'm a beginner, and I'm going to use blender to render thousands of images as a data set.In the meantime I need to use the physics engine.I was going to use bullet+blender as my solution.But you see bullet integrated into blender.

My question is:
how integrated is the bullet physics engine in blender?
Can we do all bullet through blender?
If blender can't implement all of them, what can't blender do?

cheers

Comment: What do you call "bullet engine"?

Comment: It's "bullet physics engine".Sorry for the clerical error.I found it in the blender user manual.

"Blender includes advanced physics simulation in the form of the Bullet Physics Engine (Bullet Physics). "
Link:https://easyblend.org/html/game_engine/physics/introduction.html

Comment: Rigids in Blender is an implementation of [Bullet Engine](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3) @Kiskit

Comment: Ah right, I learned something. It's very much integrated then :). That said it's hard to tell without knowing what features you're looking for whether it's going to do what you need